# Why different behavior in debug and run? Pycharm+ locals

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, local-variables

I have this code:

```
import ctypes
import inspect


def fun():
    c = 3
    inspect.currentframe().f_locals['c'] = 4
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(inspect.currentframe()), ctypes.c_int(0))
    print(c)


fun()
```

If you "Run", the output will be:
`>>> 4`

But with "Debug" and a breakpoint on "print(c)".
By calling "print(c)" to the console, the output will be like this:
`>>> 3`

Why different behavior? And can this be fixed?

Work with PyDev console pycharm

Comment: At a guess, the debugger handles the call stack in a way that is incompatible with how the `inspect` module works. (Python itself doesn't even *require* support for stack frames, so assuming your assignment changes the value of the local variable `c` relies on somewhat undefined behavior.)

Comment: I can't replicate this with VScode debugger.

Comment: It probably has something to do with how the IDE instruments the code to support debugging. It may affect the stack frames in a way that `inspect` doesn't expect.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works like this:

```
import ctypes
import inspect


def fun():
    c = 3
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_FastToLocals(ctypes.py_object(inspect.currentframe()))
    inspect.currentframe().f_locals['c'] = 4
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyFrame_LocalsToFast(ctypes.py_object(inspect.currentframe()), ctypes.c_int(0))
    print(c)


fun()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).